# Update object in List<Object> affecting specific fields only. (Merge)

Tags: java, android

I have a List of objects:

```
@Getter
@Setter
class Cat {
    int id;
    int legs;
    int head; 
} 

List<Cat> catsLegs = new ArrayList<>();
```

I fill this list with some data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    cat.setId(i);
    cat.setLegs(i + i);
    cats.add(cat);
}
```

Then I have another list

```
List<Cat> catsHeads = new ArrayList<>();
```

I fill this list with some data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    cat.setId(i);
    cat.setHead(i*i);
    cats.add(cat);
}
```

Then I want to merge this two lists and **if id is equal, then Cats are equal.**

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Cat)) {
            return false;
        }

        Cat that = (Cat) o;
        return this.id.equals(that.id);
    }
```

There are more that 3 fields, but this is a basic principle.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: it is clear what you want,  especially what you you mean by "if id is equal, then Cats are equal."?

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I made. It transfers all the objects heads and I have fresh catList.size() because I don't want old currentCats objects be in final list.

```
public static void updateCats(List<Cat> catsFromServer) {
            setAllCatsLegs(catsFromServer);
            List<Cat> currentCats = getAllCats();
            for (Cat currentCat : currentCats) {
                for (Cat fromServer : catFromServer) {
                    if (currentCat.equals(fromServer)) {
                        fromServer.setHeads(currentcat.getHeads());
                    }
                }
            }
            Contact.saveMultiple(contactsFromServer);
        }
```

upd:

```
List<Cat> currentCats = getAllCats();
        for (Cat cat : catsFromServier) {
            int index = currentCats.indexOf(cat);
            if (index != -1) {
                cat.setHeads(currentCats.get(index).getHeads);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your cats into a `Map<Integer, Cat>`
2. Get the values of the resulting `Map`
3. If you really need a `List` create a new List from the values of the `Map`

Here is how to merge the lists as you want to be able to over write:

```
Map<Integer, Cat> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Cat cat : catsLegs) {
    map.put(cat.getId(), cat);
}
for (Cat cat : catsHeads) {
    map.put(cat.getId(), cat);
}
Collection<Cat> cats = map.values();
// If you really need a List, you create a new one as next
List<Cat> catsList = new ArrayList<>(cats);
```

Comment: so, if catLegs.get(i)cat.getHeads() = null, then it will be overwriten by object in catHeads list, right?

Comment: not is not over written, if the the cat exists already it won't be added such that only the first inserted value will remain. Do you need to be able to over write?

Comment: Yes, I want over write all  fields except the legs field.

Comment: 7 only. Android compitable.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to loop through the List of cats and check `if (catHead.id == catTail.id)` but that's not really cool.

A better solution is to store your data inside a `HashMap` instead of a `List`. This way you can use the Hash Key to be the ID and the Hash Value to be the `Cat` object. Retrieving the object is much easier this way and it is of course much faster.

Comment: I can override equals and hash to compare items. I need an algorithm how to merge items